# Does the measure of proximity of two theories in "theory space" run?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, geometry

From reading [this](http://motls.blogspot.com/2012/05/lisa-randall-and-string-theory.html#more) article, I have learned that two effective QFTs can be very close together in the "theory space" appropriate to describe for example physics at the LHC scale, whereas the corresponding points in the high energy landscape of all valid theories can be far away from each other (and vice versa).

This makes me wonder how such a thing can happen, I mean:

1) Is there some kind of "renormaization flow" or beta function, that makes the measure of proximity (or metric of "theory space"?) run when one goes from the effective energy scale to high energies at about the Plankck scale (or from the Planck scale down to the effective scale)?

2) What are the mechanisms that can explain such a "duality" between short and large distances in the corresponding "theory space" when going from the effective to the high energy scale or vice versa?

Comment: Try http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0505153

Comment: @MitchellPorter I`ll try it. Prof. Strassler usually explains stuff very well. I would appreciate it too, if you could shortly explain the main points of the paper in an answer ;-). For example I did not here about duality cascades before, but is this the correct term for what I`m asking about (in my probably not precise enough wording)? Thanks anyway for the link :-)

Comment: No, but the paper explains Seiberg duality and RG flow very well, so it's good for your background knowledge. It should clarify the issues even if it doesn't answer the question.